# Azure API app not visible in Azure portal after publishing

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I published my ASP .NET Web API 2 project to Azure as an [API app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/api/). I used Visual Studio 2013 and got this lovely screen after publishing.

[image]

But the API app is no where to be found in my Azure portal.

[image]

I looked in my Visual Studio Server Explorer and it is there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the same result as yours after publishing the API app, it's just not listed when clicking **Browse > API Apps**. Although it says "**Web, Mobile and API apps are now in one list**", it obviously doesn't work as it says.

Anyway, you can alternatively find your API app in the resource group which you specified in the publishing profile:
[image]

Or, just right click the API app in **Server Explorer** and select "**Open in Management Portal**" option to open it in the portal:
[image]